# Rewrite-rules issues : .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make this URL clean:
news.php?post=13
but when I tried to use this RewriteRule:

```
    RewriteRule ^(news)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ news.php?post=$2
```

It only shows the news page, no post content.
It has been bugging me for the past 2 days, and I can`t figure it out. Can someone help me with this?

Here's the entire Htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on 

    RewriteRule ^(news)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ news.php?post=$1
    RewriteRule ^(verify)/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ validate_account.php?usr=$2&hash=$3 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(news)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ news.php?post=$2
```

use `$1`

Comment: Try removing the brackets surrounding "news". Also I'm unsure why your "news" rule has "\/" yet your"verify" rule only had "/"...

Comment: and brackets should be propably backlashed but their useless

Answer (score 1):

Try this config:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)\/?$ news.php?post=$1
RewriteRule ^verify/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ validate_account.php?usr=$1&hash=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  method:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)\/?$ news.php?post=$1
```